# How to load local file on the app driver with spark cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have run a spark cluster(standalone cluster mode), and a scala program.
The scala program may accept some `csv` file, and load `csv` into `dataset`. My code is like below:

```
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("app")
      .master("spark://172.17.0.2:7077")
      .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FIFO")
      .config("spark.memory.fraction", 0.3)
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
      .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 600)
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .getOrCreate
    sparkSession.sparkContext.addFile("file:///home/liusf/i1.csv")
    val ds = sparkSession.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("i1.csv"))
    ds.show(1)
```

but it throws a `FileNotFoundException`,error message is below

```
18:17:32  WARN [task-result-getter-0] [o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager:69] 
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.17.0.3 executor 1): 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-647c0146-5ba5-433f-9555-6b64a16231a7/userFiles-61074e0d-9edf-4c75-9857-cb9db63b3925/i1.csv does not exist
```

while in local model(`master` set as `local[1]`), it work as expected.
I've searched on google and found two sugession, one sugession is  "copy local files to all work nodes", and the other is " use nfs or hdfs to share files".
Is there a simple way that make the program work without introducing extra technology?

Answer (score 0):

By nature of clusters the job can be executed on any of the worker nodes. Unless you copy the file or store the file on a location that can be accessed by all workers spark won't be able to locate the file.

The simple way to make the program work is to `scp`the file to the desired location on all worker nodes.

Comment: The statemetn `sparkSession.sparkContext.addFile("file:///home/liusf/i1.csv")` can copy local file to all workers, but the location seems to be random. Is there a way to set a certain location? Or is there a way to read the random path on the driver ?

Comment: Once your spark session is started you cannot add more files. If you use ```spark-submit``` there is a ```--files``` option that does allow you to place files on the workers and retrieve the location of these files using ```SparkFiles.get(<filename>)```